# Run code on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, password-protection, excel-2010, vba

I have this code.

```
Const pw   As String = "password"    '<-change password here
ActiveSheet.Unprotect pw
Range("B7").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
ActiveSheet.Protect pw
```

It unprotects, refreshes data and reprotects.  Currently it runs from a button on the active sheet. I want the button to do the same thing for two different sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can set up an array of sheets to go through and using the With statement for cleaner code. If you want to do this for all sheets, you can simple say "For Each sheet in Worksheets" with no need to declare an array of sheets. :)

```
Sub Test()

Dim pw As String
pw = "password"
Dim sheet As Variant
Dim refreshSheets(1 To 2) As Worksheet

Set refreshSheets(1) = sheets(1)
Set refreshSheets(2) = sheets(2)

For Each sheet In refreshSheets
    With sheet
        .Unprotect pw
        .Range("B7").QueryTables.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Protect pw
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(someName)`.

Comment: If I wanted two sheets could you give me an example?